# Turn on stack traces for exceptions in bucklescript

Tags: ocaml, bucklescript

I'm trying to port some OCaml tests from OUnit2 to [bs-jest](https://github.com/glennsl/bs-jest), but I get a `Not_found` exception raised from some test and I don't know where it's coming from; is there a way to enable stack traces in bucklescript?

In OCaml, I would pass the `-g` option to the compiler, but it doesn't seem to do anything when calling `bsc`. When an exception is thrown and not caught the program just crashes with no info, and when I catch it and use say `Printexc.get_backtrace` I get the message "(Program not linked with -g, cannot print stack backtrace)".

Comment: I'm pretty sure bucklescript doesn't support stack traces for "native" exceptions unfortunately. You might be able to raise a JS exception instead and get a stack trace that way though.

Answer (score 0):

BuckleScript exception handling is a bit weird. Try using the techniques suggested [here](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/exceptions) to replace your exceptions with BS-style exceptions.